# Delete API Connect developer portals on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I am using API Connect on Bluemix and created a few different developer portals. After using the Trial version I want to upgrade, so I deleted my old APIC instance and provisioned a new one...but I still see my old portals. How do I delete those?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - the portal should automatically be removed by the APIM appliance when the service is removed. You can tell if the portal site has been removed or not by visiting the URL and seeing if it shows up! Apparently if there is some error or glitch and the portal site is NOT removed, then it will be cleaned up later by an automated dormancy checker.